# How to have two different portals with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is my routes.rb:

```
  scope '/staff' do
    authenticated :staff_member do
      root to: 'staff/schedule_entries#index'
    end

    unauthenticated :staff_member do
      root to: 'staff/chains#index'
    end

    scope '/:chain_id', constraints: StaffChainConstraint do
      devise_for :staff_members, path: '', controllers: {
        sessions: "staff/sessions",
        passwords: "staff/passwords",
      }, only: [:sessions, :passwords]
    end
  end

  scope '/franchisee' do
    authenticated :staff_members do
      root to: 'franchisee/locations#edit'
    end

    unauthenticated :staff_members do
      root to: 'franchisee/chains#index'
    end


    scope '/:chain_id', constraints: StaffChainConstraint do
      devise_scope :staff_member do
        get 'sign_in', to: 'franchisee/sessions#new', as: :new_franchisee_session
        post 'sign_in', to: 'franchisee/sessions#create', as: :franchisee_session
      end
    end
  end
```

The issue I'm running into is after signing from the page `franchisee/:chain_id/sign_in`, it keeps redirecting to `staff/schedule_entries#index` instead of `franchisee/locations#edit`. What am I missing to make this work?

Edit: Here's my `franchisee/sessions` controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
module Franchisee
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    helper_method :current_brand, :current_chain

    before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create, :new]

    protected

    def respond_to_on_destroy
      path = if current_admin
        admin_root_path
      else
        after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
      end
      redirect_to path
    end

    def current_chain
      @current_chain ||= Chain.find_by!(slug: params[:chain_id])
    end

    def current_brand
      current_chain.brand
    end

    def configure_sign_in_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:username, :password])
    end

    def set_raven_context
      Raven.tags_context(app: 'franchisee')
      Raven.user_context(
        type: 'franchisee',
        username: params.dig(:staff_member, :username),
        brand_slug: current_brand&.slug,
        chain_slug: params[:chain_id],
      )
    end
  end
end
```

I made sure this controller is hit when submitting the sign in form from the page `franchisee/:chain_id/sign_in`. I also tried to fiddle around with `after_sign_in_for` but wasn't able to figure out a good way for it to tell between `staff` and `franchisee`.

Comment: Can you verify that the `franchise`  form is indeed getting submitted to the `franchise/sessions#create` action and not the `staff` sessions controller?

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes it is submitting to `franchisee/sessions#create`.

Comment: Cool, Can you share the code from that controller then please?

Comment: @RockwellRice I edited my question with the controller.

Comment: I feel like you will likely need to take control of this in the controller by updating the create method which is in the Devise Controller.  When you run the sign in, in the log you can see what is being called.  Is this the point where it directs to the other route you want to avoid?  I mean, when it hits the create method here does it then redirect to the route you do not want?

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes it redirects to the route I don't want after hitting `franchisee/sessions#create`. I put a hack to `after_sign_in_for` to resolve this for now, but I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong with my routes. One thing to note is that going to `/franchisee` after logged in does not redirect to the `authenticated :staff_member` path under the `franchisee` scope so I think I should fix this in my routes set up.

Comment: Well  I assume they both inherit from the same devise controller right? I'm not sure it is the routes, since it is the same action being used for both you need to override that in the controller and direct it there.